# Why is parking not allowed under some overhead power lines?

Tags: high-voltage, power-engineering

At work, among others, we have overhead power lines for the main grid connection (400 kV, about 1600 MW). The power lines cross a parking lot, and the positions directly under the power lines are blocked with large rocks.

There are some ideas about the reason why parking is not allowed under the power lines, including protection from exposure to electric and magnetic fields, protection from falling ice (it’s in a Nordic country), protection from downed power lines, protection of the power lines (which need a very high availability) from accidents (i.e. fire) of parked cars, and accessibility of power lines for maintenance (however, moving any cars would be easier than removing the rocks).

Anyway, what is the real reason why parking is not allowed under the power lines?

Comment: A photo might help. Add one in.

Comment: Falling ice for sure!

Comment: You say "at work", but is the parking lot part of the company building, or is it a public area? Who has issued the prohibition? Is it a company rule or something mandated by the municipality? The answer might be also highly country-specific in this latter case.

Comment: Question which call for speculation do not really fit the stack exchange model - doubly so when they are questions of *policy* even before questions of fact.

Comment: I would say all of the above. As any of these are serious hazards.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yep, as formulated this is not really a good fit for EE.SE. It would be better if formulated like "what are the risks of parking under power lines". That would call forth technical facts.

Comment: One word: Birds.

Comment: It isn't that you can't park under the lines, it is that you can't park ACROSS the lines. If you were to park such that your car is parallel with the lines you would be fine. When you park perpendicular to the lines the fields generated by the lines would generate a charge on your car. My brother works in construction and they made everyone aware of this on the site. One guy missed the meeting and had to have his car discharged before he could get out. This only applies to the really high voltage power lines though.

Comment: It's not "charging" the car or generating a charge, its mutual inductance.

Answer (score 5):

The comment about charging up the vehicle seems to be spot on.  [This safety publication about Overhead High Voltage Lines](http://www.bpa.gov/news/pubs/GeneralPublications/lusi-Living-and-working-safely-around-high-voltage-power-lines.pdf) says the following.

> Under some high-voltage lines, vehicles can 
>   collect an induced voltage. This is particularly true 
>   if the vehicle is parked on a nonconductive surface 
>   such as asphalt or dry rock. You can drain the 
>   voltage from your vehicle to the ground by attach-
>   ing a chain that reaches the ground or by leaning a 
>   metal bar against your vehicle. The only way to be 
>   sure you won’t get shocked is to park your car 
>   away from the high-voltage power line.

Comment: That's rather interesting. To collect an induced voltage suggests a static charge which in turn suggests rectification through the wheels / tyres. Anyone got any ideas?